# Pixelated CSS text-shadow issue on Safari/iOS but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari, text-shadow

I have a strange problem with `text-shadow` on a large title in Safari. There seem to be pixelated boxes in the shadow on Safari, whilst on Chrome it looks great. Does anyone know why this might happen? I couldn't find anything online about this issue.

CSS for the element (I put it all in just in case there is something relevant):

```css
.title {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-size: calc(50px + 5vmin);
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 60px black;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Chrome:
[image: Chrome rendering]

Safari:
[image: Safari rendering]

Comment: Safari is just terrible. Sometimes we've had to use a 3d transform to "trick" Safari into using hardware acceleration to fix/address odd rendering issues. See if adding something like `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` fixes it.

Comment: Try something like `filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 60px black);` instead of `text-shadow`. The result might not be exactly the same but it does get rid of the pixelated artifact.

Comment: @DrewReese that one didn't work unfortunately, but thanks for the reply!

Comment: @HaoWu this was perfect! Looks great on both browsers now. I've never heard of filter but will keep it in mind going forward. Thanks so much!

Comment: That's the joy of CSS. Sometimes there's 100 ways to do something, sometimes only exactly 1, and sometimes that 1 thing is different in each browser. Just keep filling up your CSS "bag-O-tricks".